# Android: Implement favorites in list view

Tags: android, favorites

HI,

My app is about a directory of places where a user can see list of places close to his location and view details of that place.

I want to "add to my favorites" functionality for all the items in list view and detail page view.

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking to do it using CheckBox but was not able to understand how to implement in listview adapter.

I am thinking of the following table straucture for favorites:
_id - integer primary key
content_identifier - unique identifier for the place (text)

Can someone please help?

Regards,
Sapan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom listview(check how to create a custom listview and add listeners to it)
and add a checkbox or an image , add a listener(click listener) to the image of the list   items, whenever image or checkbox is pressed , add a database entry ( favorites table or so)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented it but facing a small issue: On listing page if the favorite star is checked and then we go to detail page. On detail page, we see favorite star checked which is correct behaviour. But when i uncheck it and go back to listing page I see the favorite button still checked. This is because list view is not getting updated with the action on detail page. Can anything be done for this?

Comment: From the details view , send the state back to your listview activity , check startActiviyForResult and communicating between activites, if there is a state change in details view , send back that status to the activity containing listview and set the adapter(updating listview) accordingly.